# Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $pq$ where $(p,q)=1$. Assume that $a,b\in G$ whose orders are $p$ and $q$, respectively. Show that $G$ is cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

My knowledge on group theory is limited only up to the Lagrange Theorem, and it seems that the proofs I found here use more advanced theorems. What are the facts that I should know to prove this one?

I am trying to come up with an element $c \in G$ such that $\langle c\rangle = G$. I'm thinking of letting $c=ab$. Do you think this will lead to the desired result?

Comment: What is the order of $c$? The order of $c$ will be the size of the subgroup generated by $c$.

Comment: Use Lagrange's Theorem to verify that $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle=\{1\}$. Then use that to show that if $a^ib^j=1$, then $a^i=b^j=1$. Then use *that* to show that the order of $c$ must be $pq$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to sketch a simple proof.
Let $c=ab$ and consider the product $cc...c=abab...ab$. Since $G$ is abelian, $ab=ba$ and so $abab...ab=a^nb^m$.

Let $|ab|=r$. Then $(ab)^r=a^r b^r=1$, hence $a^r=b^{-r}$. So  $a^r$ is an inverse for $b^r$ and hence $a^r∈〈b〉$. But by the Lagrange’s Theorem $〈a〉  ⋂ 〈b〉=1$, what forces $a^r=1$ and hence  $|a|=p \ |\  r$. Analogously from $a^r b^r=1$ follows $a^{-r}=b^r$, so  $b^r$ is an inverse for $a^r$, hence $b^r∈〈a〉$ and since $〈a〉  ⋂ 〈b〉=1$ it must be $b^r=1$ and hence  $|b|=q \ | \ r$. Thus $r$ is divisible by both $p,q$ and since we’re looking for minimal such $r$ (as an order of $ab$), it follows that $r=lcm(p,q)$. Since $gcd(p,q)=1$, we have $lcm(p,q)=pq$.

Thus $|ab|=pq$ and since $|G|=pq$, it follows that $ab$ is a generator of $G$. So, $G=〈ab〉=〈c〉$ is cyclic.

Comment: The fact that the product is $1$ "only when $n$ reaches $p$ and $m$ reaches $q$" already uses the fact that $\gcd(p,q)=1$. Without it, the claim could be false.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin. Yes, that's true, thanks. I've edited the proof.

Answer (score 0):

First, we show $\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle=\{ e\}$. Assume this is not true, so exsits $x\neq e, x\in \langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle$. Let $d=|\langle x\rangle|\Rightarrow d\ge 2$. Since $\langle x\rangle\le \langle a\rangle$ and $\langle x\rangle\le \langle b\rangle$, then we have $d|p$ and $d|q$, hence $1=\gcd(p, q)\ge d\ge2$, contradiction.

Next, it is easy to check $c=ab, c^{pq}=e$, so we need to show $|\langle c\rangle|=pq$. Assume, this is not true, namely, exsits $k<pq$, such that $c^k=e$. Then we get

$$a^k=b^{-k}=y\Rightarrow y\in \langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle\Rightarrow y=e $$

$$\Rightarrow a^k=b^k=e\Rightarrow p|k, q|k$$

Since $\gcd(p, q)=1$, we get $$pq|k\Rightarrow k\ge pq$$

Contradiction.

Comment: Why argue by contradiction? If $x\in\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle$, then $|x|$ divides both $p$ and $q$, hence divides $1$, so $x=e$. Conclude $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle = \{1\}$. Arguing by contradiction when there is absolutely no need to do so, and where the assumption is never used until you are done with the direct proof is bad (though sadly extremely common) practice.